# Displaying bare metal firmware output in QEMU window

Tags: arm, qemu, firmware

I am debugging a proprietary binary firmware which uses the functions "puts" and "putc" to print to screen.
The problem is that the print functions use specific addresses to print to (I do not know if these MMIO addresses use UART\SPI\Serial interface to print)

Here is the decompiled version of the putc function:

```
void putc(int chr)
{
    while (unk_64000018 & 20);
    unk_64000000 = chr;
    v1 = off_20000AA0;
    current_offset = *off_20000AA0;
    if ( *off_20000AA0 < 500 )
    {
        *(dword_20000AA4 + current_offset) = chr;
        *v1 = current_offset + 1;    
    }
 }
```

How can I make these debug prints show in the QEMU window?

Currently I am running this firmware by the following command line and it works out of the box:
qemu-system-arm.exe -machine cubieboard -m 4g -kernel firmware.bin -gdb tcp::1234 -S

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the firmware binary is printing by writing to some sort of serial port hardware at address 0x64000000 (which may not be the same as the physical address of the UART if it has the MMU on).

To get these to do the right thing you need to have a model of the actual hardware your firmware expects to run on. If that's not the same as the Allwinner A10 that the cubieboard has then this isn't going to work (unless you modify QEMU to add an emulation of whatever device this is).

Comment: This is my exact question, how to modify QEMU to add an emulation of the device?

Comment: That is a non-trivial task. You can look at the source code and follow what existing device models do; there is not particularly any documentation on how to do it.